# What effect in the current will have the change of the diameter of coil but same length of coil and same magnetic flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

[image: 1]

First image is one coil with the large diameter and a magnet rotating to create current in the coil. Second image is the same set but the diameter of coil is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

The induced voltage according to Faradays Law is

$$V= - N\frac{\Delta \Phi}{\Delta t}$$

where $\Phi$ is the flux $\Phi = BA$, where $B$ is the magnetic field strength and $A$ is the area of the coil,  $A=\pi r^2$ where $r$ is the radius of the coil.

The induced current will be from $$V=IR$$

You can decide whether you require the magnetic field strength or magnetic flux to be constant.  Also whether the same length of wire means the same resistance, but more turns $N$.  When you put all these together you'll be to decide how the induced current in the coil changes.